# From SQL server, extract a list of Users containing the list of all their bought application (mapping table)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Let Users be a database containing typical users data (name, email...) with an ID as primary key.

Let `Applications` be a database storing a list of applications (name, developer...) with an ID as primary key.

Let `UsersApps` be the mapping table between the two, using the primary key. UsersApps thus stores rows of `..., {102, user1_Id, appA_Id}, {103, userN_ID, appB_Id}, {104, user1_Id, appC_Id}, ...` 
And so on.

I want to retrieve a list of users data `{name, email, List<Application> boughtApps}`

I am struggling to find a LINQ request to do that and I am trying to do it in two steps, get a big table and then build each user's list of applications.

```
            var q1 = from user in _dbContext.Users
                     join appUti in _dbContext.AppUsers on user.Id equals appUti.UsersId
                     join app in _dbContext.Applications on appUti.ApplicationId equals app.Id
                     orderby user.Id
                     select new UserDataWithApp { Id = user.Id, Name = user.Name, firstName= user.FirstName, Email = user.Email, App = app };
```

Then parse `q1.toList()` to build my required results list.

```
       var qRes = q1.ToList();
       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
        while (i<qRes.Count())
        {
                listUsersWithApps[j] = qRes[i];
                while (qRes[i].Id == listUsersWithApps[j].Id) // llist is ordered !!
                {
                    listUsersWithApps[j].Apps.Add(qRes[i].Apps[0]);
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
     }
```

Isn't there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigation properties to allow the following:

```
var userApps = context.Users.Select(u => new UserWithApp(u.Name, u.Email, u.Applications))
```

Just add to following to `User`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
```

and to `Application`:

```
public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
```

So you can "navigate" between your entities and write to following query (just adapt your ordering and what user data to be seleted):

```
var userApps = from user in context.Users
               select new UserDataWithApp { ..., BoughtApps = user.Applications }
```

See here for an example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

or another interesting blog: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how you went from the fluent api to your one liner :( Anyway, I can't just configure again the DB, I used an automatic generator.

Comment: Just try to understand the example in the first link. don't focus on the linq query, it's not that important. you don't need to modify your database structure. I will edit my post to add some details.